# Overloading << operator c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, overloading, nodes, operator-keyword

I am trying to output the values of my linked lists, but I can't seem to get my operator<< to work. When I out << previous->key;   It comes out as -1, which is what the HEAD_OF_LIST is. In the program, I call the function l[2] = LLSortedPosInt(2); which sets list #2 to contain one element which is the integer 2.

This is the Class declaration:

```
struct  Node;
typedef Node* NodePtr;

// The key value HEAD_OF_LIST is used as a "sentinal" value
const int HEAD_OF_LIST = -1;

class LLSortedPosInt {
  public:
   // constructors
                         LLSortedPosInt();
                         LLSortedPosInt(int  key);
                         LLSortedPosInt(int *keys,  int n);         //int *keys is an array of integers
                         LLSortedPosInt(const LLSortedPosInt &l);

   // destructor
                        ~LLSortedPosInt();

   bool                  containsElement (int key) const;
   bool                  isEmpty         (       ) const;

   LLSortedPosInt&       operator= (const LLSortedPosInt &l);
   bool                  operator==(const LLSortedPosInt &l) const;
   bool                  operator!=(const LLSortedPosInt &l) const;

   friend LLSortedPosInt operator+ (const LLSortedPosInt &l1,
                                      const LLSortedPosInt &l2);
   friend LLSortedPosInt operator- (const LLSortedPosInt &l1,
                                      const LLSortedPosInt &l2);
   friend ostream&       operator<<(ostream &out, 
                                      const LLSortedPosInt &l);
  private:
   void                  insert    (int key);
   void                  remove    (int key);

   NodePtr head;
};
```

This is the createNode function:

```
static NodePtr createNode(int key, NodePtr p) {
   // allocate a new Node for storing the given key value
   NodePtr n = new Node;

   // store the key value and the next pointer
   n->key  = key;
   n->next = p;

   // return the new Node to the caller
   return n;
}
```

This is my code for the operator<<

```
ostream&  operator<<  (ostream &out, const LLSortedPosInt &l) {

// an empty list will be printed as <>
// a singleton list (a list having one key value k) will be
//     printed as <k>
// a list having multiple keys such as 2, 5, 7 will be printed
//     as <2, 5, 7>

// print the left angle bracket
out << "<";

NodePtr previous = l.head;
NodePtr current = l.head->next;

//TEST previous AND current
out << previous->key;
out << current->key << ">" << endl << "<";

// print the values of l
while (current != NULL) {
    if (current->key >= 0) {
        if (current->next == NULL) {
            out << current->key;
            break;
        }
        out << current << ", ";
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
}

// print the right angle bracket
out << ">";

return out;
}
```

I also have a function that takes an integer input which is below. I am pretty sure this is written correctly, but I am not sure.

```
LLSortedPosInt::LLSortedPosInt(int key) {
// create the sentinal Node at the head of the list
head = createNode(HEAD_OF_LIST, nullptr);

// add the single element key, as long as it is positive
if (key > 0) {
    head->next = createNode(key, nullptr);
}
}
```

Comment: Where is your operator declared? And what exactly is not working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here.It's specially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: The first `current = l.head->next;` looks dangerous. What if `l.head` is `nullptr`?

Comment: Can you describe what you are getting? A crash, or a wrong text? I do see one bug that could produce wrong text: `out << previous->key;` and immediately 
`out << current->key`. The text will be concatenated: did you forget a comma? Also, @TedLyngmo has a good point (crashing).

Comment: @michaelVeksler    I am outputting  <-1>  which is what head->key is (HEAD_OF_LIST = -1). but when I uncomment   out << current->key;   My program segment faults and crashes.

Comment: @KP1O8 Why does `head` have a special value? If it's always going to be `-1`, can't you just leave that out of the linked list? What do you get if you try the suggestion I made in my answer?

Comment: *but when I uncomment out << current->key; My program segment faults and crashes*. So here is your problem: current is `nullptr`. Check if the pointer is null before dereferencing and printing what it points to

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want the question  get closed, you should update the question with the clarifications you made in the comments

Comment: You should comment out the two lines after `// TEST previous AND current` and the printing code will be correct. After that, your true problem lies elsewhere since the list is empty. Possible causes are: the element was removed by `remove(key)`, or the copy/assignment were invoked but have a bug in them. We need more information, as the bug can't be reproduced with the given code

Comment: Also, `    LLSortedPosInt ll(5);
    std::cout << ll << "\n";
` works fine (after commenting out the two lines before the while). so the bug is elsewhere

Answer (score -1):

The definition of `operator<<` could be:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const LLSortedPosInt& l) {
    out << "<";
    NodePtr current = l.head;
    // check that it actually points to a Node before accessing any fields
    if(current) {
        out << current->key;
        // loop through the links and stream the keys
        while((current = current->next) != nullptr)
            out << "," << current->key;
    }
    out << ">";
    return out;
}
```

The constructor `LLSortedPosInt(int key)` should not create a `HEAD_OF_LIST` node since it's not used for anything. So you can change that constructor to use the one you already have for a list of keys via delegation. Delegation also makes it easy to add a constructor using an `initializer_list`:

```
LLSortedPosInt(const int *keys=nullptr, size_t n=0) :
    head(nullptr)
{
    if(keys && n) {
        while(n--) {
            createNode(*keys);
            ++keys;
        }
    }
}

// single key construction
LLSortedPosInt(int key) :
    LLSortedPosInt(&key, 1) // delegate
{}

// construction using an initializer list
LLSortedPosInt(std::initializer_list<int> il) :
    LLSortedPosInt(il.begin(), il.size()) // delegate
{}
```

The `static createNode` interface is a little odd. Users of the function shouldn't need to supply the pointer to the next node. That's what the container class is for. It could be made into a normal member function and create the node in the correct place directly:

```
NodePtr createNode(int key) {
    NodePtr current = head;
    NodePtr previous = nullptr;

    while(current && (current->key < key)) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    if(previous) {
        // insert the node between previous and previous->next
        NodePtr rv = new Node(key, previous->next);
        return previous->next = rv;
    } else {
        // insert the node first in the list
        NodePtr rv = new Node(key, head);
        return head = rv;
    }
}
```

Given that the actual `Node` looks something like this:

```
struct Node {
    Node* next;
    int key;
    Node(int k, Node* n) : next(n), key(k) {}
    Node(const Node&) = delete;
    Node(Node&&) = delete;
    Node& operator=(const Node&) = delete;
    Node& operator=(Node&&) = delete;
    ~Node() = default;
};

using NodePtr = Node*;
```

Comment: Implementing this code, current->key is still equal to -1.   When I run the program, I am calling the function   l[2] = LLSortedPosInt(2);   Which should set list #2 to contain the integer 2.

Comment: Does it crash? If you always set `head->key` to `-1`, it's not surprising that the first node will always have a key value of `-1`. What purpose does that node have? And what's `l[2]`? Do you have an array of `LLSortedPosInt`s? You need to show the code for `createNode` too. Edit your question and put that function in it.

Comment: Yes, but I set head->next to the key value. I set head to -1 for any case that a given list is empty, because then head->next == nullptr, which with the operator<< should output "<>".    Yes, I have a set of 5 lists, l[1] - l[5].   Sorry, I am new to pointers and classes and all this, so I am still trying to learn and grasp this.

Comment: If the code I wrote crashes, I think the linked list is broken somehow. Why not let `head` be `nullptr` when the list is empty? That's how it's normally done.

Comment: head->next  IS  nullptr. Your code does not crash, but outputs <-1> Like before.

Comment: I'm not saying `head->next`. I'm saying `head`.

Comment: Please explain the downvote so that I know what to improve.

Comment: Thanks, but someone did, which is a little odd since it contains solutions for both the crash and the `<-1>` problem - and I did try explaining how in the comments of the code. I'd really like to know why it's not considered to be a useful answer to learn how to improve.